# Writing tenant aware web service in wso2 application server

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, wso2, multi-tenant

I am trying to develop a axis2 web service to be deployed on WSO2 Application Server 5.0.1. Currently we have requirement, that web services support multi-tenancy and in some web services some process based on tenant. Upon the service context i need to retrieve tenant information from the current request. Currently i create to tenant in my local environment using Application Server management console test1.com and test2.com. How can i retrieve domain name and if possible tenant id of test1.com and test2.com from request and how should client call the web service to a specific tenant, for example to test1.com ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CarbonContext](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.context/4.0.1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/context/CarbonContext.java) to retrieve current tenant and other stuffs.

```
 CarbonContext cCtx = CarbonContext.getCurrentContext();
    cCtx.getTenantDomain();
    cCtx.getTenantId();
```

Refer [this article](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/03/carbon-context-its-usages-wso2-products) for more information on how to use carbon platform APIs.