# WSO2 Sharing super tenant web service to other tenants

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant

I would like to share web service which is deployed in super tenant to other tenants. As far as I know everyone can access the super admin services if they are using http:// localhost :8280/services/echo?wsdl url. But I do not want just to access super tenant application, I would also like to see request count on correct tenant. Should I have to deploy the same application to every tenant and call service with proper url (http:// localhost .com:8280/services/t/tenantname/echo?wsdl) to collect the request counts?

Is there any other way to do this? For example maybe I could put header variable to my request which is showing, which tenant is calling the application etc., and with this kind of approach, I do not have to deploy my service to other tenants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.Utils class has a function which name is getTenantDomain.

I have changed this methods to find tenant domain from headers, so it is working like a charm :)

I think WSO2 also thinks to customize this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code something like,

```
int tenantId = MultitenantUtils.getTenantId(this.getConfigContext());
```

to get the tenant ID of the current tenant and send it either in the message itself or in the header. Then you can record the tenants accessed in the server side, by counting the tenant IDs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154536/1774964) will help you to get the tenant ID.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Maninda, However i do not want to write code  for counting request. WSO2 could already count the request if i call web service with tenant url. I just want the know wso2 could count request with proper tenant if i send the request with header or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to deploy the application at each tenant. Then you get a separate URL for each. 
Or else you can make your service multi tenant aware. For this you need to make the service secured. When log into the service, we can determine the tenant using the user name. For an example foo user should be a super tenant user while foo@bar.com should belongs to bar.com tenant. In this case carbon framework, does this authentication and set the tenant details to carbon context. You can access that at the service level. eg. CarbonContext.getCurrentContext().getTenantID() or with the method Maninda has mentioned.